# ActiveAdmin passing variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a permit and vehicle model. I am trying to update the AA create controller to work how I have it in my rails app. That is taking the vehicle license_number entered and inputting it into the permit table, then also taking the inputted permit_id and inputting it into the permits attribute of the vehicle it is related to in the vehicle table.

**admin/permit.rb**

```
permit_params :permit_id, :vehicle, :date_issued, :issued_by, :date_entered, :entered_by

form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :permit_id
        f.input :vehicle, :collection => Vehicle.all.map{ |vehicle| [vehicle.license_number]}
        f.input :date_issued, as: :date_picker
        f.input :issued_by
    end
    f.actions
end

controller do
    def new
        @permit = Permit.new
        @vehicle = @permit.build_vehicle
        @vehicle = Vehicle.all 
        super
    end 

    def create
         vehicle = Vehicle.find_by(license_number: permit_params[:vehicle_attributes][:license_number])
         @permit = current_user.permit.build(permit_params.merge(date_entered: Date.today, 
            entered_by: current_user_admin.email))
         super
    end
end
```

My errors that I am getting, is that it is inputting the license_number in for the permit_id and then it is also saying the permit_params is not a defined variable. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting case here: it is confusing because you have a model called `Permit`, and usually in Rails you name the params method something like `permit_params`. Turns out, `permit_params` is the general method signature for ActiveRecord to implement strong params: https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html

With that, instead of calling `permit_params` in your `create` action, you need to call `permitted_params[:vehicle_attributes][:license_number]`. That’s why it’s considering `permit_params` as an undefined variable. Again, those two method signatures will be the same for all your ActiveAdmin forms.

Additionally, I’m not sure if this is a typo but you define `@vehicle` twice in your `new` method. I’m not sure you need to build a vehicle for the permit form unless you’re doing nested forms. Either way, I think the last line should read `@vehicles = Vehicle.all`  Then you can use that in your form, which also could use an update in the `collection` part of your form field:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :permit_id
    f.input :vehicle, collection: @vehicles.map { |vehicle| [vehicle.license_number, vehicle.id] }
    f.input :date_issued, as: :date_picker
    f.input :issued_by
  end
  f.actions
end
```

The `collection_select` form tag will take the first item in the array as the value that appears in the form, and the second value will be the value passed through in the params (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select).

Then in your `create` action, you can find the Vehicle with the id:

`Vehicle.find(permitted_params[:vehicle_attributes][:vehicle_id])`

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid Permit as a model name, try using VehiclePermit.