# ActiveAdmin create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to add to my create controller in AA and I just keep getting errors and it also is not passing one of my form values.

**admin/vehicle_permit.rb**

```
permit_params :utf8, :vehicle_permit_id, :vehicle, :date_issued, :issued_by, :date_entered, :entered_by,
    vehicle_attributes: [:license_number, :vehicle_permit_id]

form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.has_many :vehicle, new_record: false do |veh|
            veh.input :license_number, :collection => Vehicle.all.map{ |vehicle| [vehicle.license_number]}
        end
        f.input :vehicle_permit_id
        f.input :date_issued, as: :date_picker
        f.input :issued_by
    end
    f.actions
end

controller do
    def new
        @vehicle_permit = VehiclePermit.new
        @vehicle = @vehicle_permit.build_vehicle 
    end 

    def create

         vehicle = Vehicle.find_by(license_number: vehicle_permit_params[:vehicle_attributes][:license_number])
         @vehicle_permit = current_user.vehicle_permit.build(vehicle_permit_params.merge(date_entered: Date.today, entered_by: current_admin_user.email[:vehicle_permit])
         @vehicle_permit.update(vehicle: vehicle)
         super
    end

    def update
        super           
    end

    def vehicle_permit_params
        params.permit vehicle_permit: [:vehicle_permit_id, :date_issued, :issued_by, :date_entered, :entered_by,  vehicle_attributes: [:license_number]]
    end

    def set_vehicle_permit
        @vehicle_permit = VehiclePermit.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I am trying to add the current date into the date_entered field, and the current admin user email value into the entered by field. I am getting the error that vehicle_permit is NIL so I do not know why it isn't passing in the params I've indicated. The form is also not passing in the `:vehicle` input field and I am not sure how to grab that so I can input the value selected it into a different model/table.

**EDIT**

This is the application trace of the parameters being passed.

```
app/admin/vehicle_permit.rb:60:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"JeyVHNsSyGi4U22RbsplTexSawKEj3QYAItAFNXrn601zL0n6nu+pkCObkTmY0Du3wd1TN3BWLXaGyGt48glUw==",
"vehicle_permit"=>{"vehicle_permit_id"=>"AU-4444", "date_issued"=>"", 
"issued_by"=>""},
"commit"=>"Create Vehicle permit"}
```

**EDIT 2** 
I realized I wasn't using nested attributes properly, I edited my form to have the nested attribute license_number which is coming from vehicle. Now I am getting a nil return in my `find_by` and I'm not sure why it is not finding the vehicle in the vehicle table.

Comment: Why do you have the :vehicle_permit in here `entered_by: current_admin_user.email[:vehicle_permit]`

Comment: Because when I didn't, I was getting the not able to pass `UTF8` attribute error.

Comment: Hey there, could you take another look at this prior answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497300/activeadmin-passing-variable-in-controller  I see that you still define your collection tag differently (but I guess let me know if how you’re doing it is working for you). Additionally take another look at the ActiveAdmin documentation (https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html). `permitted_params` is already an AA method, you’re overriding it here in your code.

Comment: Could you post the params coming in if you’re still having trouble?

Comment: I posted the params that were getting passed. I also edited the `permitted_params` and changed it to `vehicle_permit_params` which is what I had have had it before. I knew `permitted_params` was a AA method, I've really just been trying different names/methods to get it to work.

Comment: quick question - when I user is filling out this form to make a permit, are they ever creating a vehicle? can a permit have more than one vehicle assigned to it? Can you post your model associations and /or your schema?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UrS4Eevc

Here is a pastebin to the schema because its 120 lines long. The user does not create a vehicle from here, the vehicle is already created. Then they find the vehicle via license_number in the select, then it creates the permit in the permit table, and then it is supposed to also input the permit number into the `vehicle_permit_id` field in the vehicle table via FK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Let's break this down a little. Instead of `has_many` try just having a dummy 'virtual' field for license_number. You might need attr_accessor :license_number on VehiclePermit.

```
form do |f|
    license_collection = Vehicle.all.map{ |vehicle| [vehicle.license_number] }
    f.inputs do
        f.input :license_number, collection: license_collection
        # f.input :vehicle_permit_id # Not needed??
        f.input :date_issued, as: :date_picker
        f.input :issued_by
    end
    f.actions
end
```

permit_params should follow the structure of the form, not the models.

```
permit_params :date_issued, :issued_by, :license_number # form fields only
# There should be no need for any other permit methods
```

If all is well you should be able to `puts params.inspect` at the top of `create` and see the values from the form.

```
def create
  license_number = params[:vehicle_permit].delete(:license_number)

  build_resource # this should set resource = VehiclePermit.build(params[:vehicle_permit])

  resource.vehicle = Vehicle.find_by(license_number: license_number)
  resource.date_entered = Date.today
  resource.entered_by = current_user

  super
end
```

Try stepping through with pry and/or sprinkling with puts inspect in case I missed something.

Comment: I flipped your associations in my head, Bryce. This answer should get you what you want, and if so, please accept it. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: This worked, I completely missed the `attr_accessor: license_number` part and that is why the form was not working for me. Thank you very much for both of your help.